# Would voting for posts based on their score be considered fraud?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, serial-voting

We can use the Advanced Search feature to find questions with a specific score. If I were to use the function to find posts with say 9, 24, 99, or 39 (for accepted answers) and give them an up-vote to award the post with a badge, would this be considered a form of voting fraud?

I would *not be* targeting specific users, just the score. I would also give evaluation to each post and not blindly up-vote *every* post with those scores.

Comment: are you asking if the votes are _proper_, or are you asking if you found a loophole in the voting-fraud-detection algorithm?

Comment: @KutuluMike If they are proper. I like the badge system, and would like to see more awarded. Again, I *will* evaluate the post before voting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fine as long as you [evaluate each post for its *content*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284059/299342).

There is nothing in the relevant help center articles which suggest that this would be fraud.

- [Privileges: Vote Up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
- [Why is voting important?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)
- [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Answer (score 6):

Blindly upvoting every post with such score wouldn't be OK, but as long as you read each of them to determine whether it's worth an upvote, I don't see anything wrong with that.