# Why automatically upvoting all answers with 0 votes by users with a reputation >10000 is a bad idea

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, experience

This came up once as an idea to improve SO:

> Experienced users' answers should be shown above answers of new users. Giving all answers with no votes a free upvote on all Users with at least 10.000 rep would enhance the whole system.

Please add some explanation, why that is a bad idea

Comment: Reputation is an indicator for how much the site/network valued the user contribution. But is not a clear representation . One user could have some amazing posts and reached 10k but doesnt mean that every answer the user writes deserve 1 upvote. And being new doesnt mean your answer is less valid than others.

Comment: Experienced users are already advantaged enough over new users by knowing the rules, what questions are more likely to draw attention and how to write posts likely to draw upvotes, not to mention the implicit seal of approval that comes with the big number next to their name. We don't need to make it even harder for new users to get started here.

Comment: So your feature request is to just upvote all answers with 0 votes?  This is a horrible idea.  It would upvote thousands comments, incorrectly submitted as an answer, but not yet removed by the community making it even harder to remove those non-answers.

Comment: Merely being high-rep doesn't mean that a user's contribution to any particular question is automatically good, or even automatically better than the contribution by the rankest newbie posting his first answer/comment.

Comment: Can you imagine the rep inflation? Users with higher rep would get even MORE auto-robotically, gain higher visibility, and be disproportionately awarded even more auto-accepted answers. The community's reputation distribution would go parabolic.

Comment: What should we do with this obvious bad idea? I would like to leave it here as example and so others would not suggest the same again. But it is getting down voted more and more

Comment: see [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: Thanks, I hope, I rephrased it in the right manner now, that I got it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a poor idea:

1. You vote on the answer, **not** the answerer.
2. An amount of reputation is a measure of the contributions made by the answerer, not necessarily their level of expertise on that particular topic.
3. A fair few high reputation users answer questions that are later found to be duplicates. An answer upvote can circumvent automatic removal of duplicates.
4. This would instigate a positive feedback mechanism whereby your reputation grows arbitrarily once a certain level is reached.

Finally, high reputation users can also make mistakes, and the voting mechanism serves as a very effective peer review process. Let's not distort it. By way of an example, if you have 10k on Stack Overflow, you can see a net +4 answer of mine that was proven to be incorrect; an automatic upvote would have only added further distortion. See [Replace c-style cast (long&) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370971/replace-c-style-cast-long-in-c/50371176#50371176)

Answer (score 24):

No, this a bad idea. It violates one of the [general Stack Exchange principles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232):

> Vote for the content, not for the user.

I'm not sure if there are any hard facts about this, but my gut feeling says posts by high reputation users are already more likely to be upvoted by people thinking along the lines of "that user has a lot of reputation, so he/she knows what he/she's talking about".

Comment: I do not think it is possible to sufficiently emphasize the statement in your quote block.

Answer (score 1):

This would not be a good idea. It would automatically upvote lots of false answers that were just not noticed before. And It would make it harder to find duplicate or false answers for the moderators. Also it would be demotivating for new users if they notice that others get one upvote for free.