# Is there any way to track the users who I have personally upvoted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, users

A coworker of mine just stated:

> It's crazy you remember their names

When I mentioned something along the lines of

> *You should trust the answer from , I find they know their stuff*

Which led to further discussion about how reputation is not always good enough (given how easy it is to get [a lot of reputation for an obvious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31172318/516433)).  To that end, I was wondering if there was a way to get a report of who I have previously upvoted.  Better yet, would it be possible to put a little `+<myUpvoteCount>` next to a users answer?  Maybe even share my counts with my team/friends/coworkers?

Comment: You need to scrape [votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes)

Comment: There's not much value in doing so IMO. Everyone has their _"bad hair day"_ from time to time, and not every answer of a particular person is outstanding _brilliant_.

Comment: Just remember you shouldn't be upvoting anything because of whom wrote it.

Comment: I am not saying that I would/or should upvote because of who wrote it, and I am fully aware that people have _bad hair days_.  My point is that when I look back at all the answers I have already upvoted (for valid reasons), there are some people whose answers feature more prominently.  This is more of a _personal trust metric_ that I am suggesting.  One I could share with others among my teams.  But looks like there are not a lot of people who agree :(.

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering if there was a way to get a report of who I have previously upvoted.

No, all you can get is (manually) checking the ['upvote' tab in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote). Note that it only shows the title and (upon expanding) the content of the post. This fits nicely with one of the core Stack Exchange principles: [Vote for the content, not the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232). I'm sure that with decent JavaScript skills you'd be able to retrieve the user details from the links.

In some circumstances, the following trick might be helpful:
The past few days I've been working a lot with NEST, a .NET client library for ElasticSearch. I can go over to the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nest/topusers) page and make a mental note of who the knowledgeable users are in this subject. Still, I'd rather check an *answer*'s score before browsing user information. A lot of great Stack Exchange answers have been written by 'one-day flies'; the score tells you that a lot of other Stack Exchange members found a certain answer helpful.