# Can I accept a self-answer with content from outside Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer, attribution

Here is my motivation: [How to convert estimated precision to variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350235/how-to-convert-estimated-precision-to-variance). On the one hand, the provided answer is perfect in my opinion and could be accepted, but on the other hand it is not actually *my* answer (I asked the same question on another mailing list, and I simply copied the answer here), so it'd perhaps strange to accept it as if I myself have answered it.

What to do now? Should I accept it...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the correct answer, accept it. Since you posted the answer yourself, you won't gain reputation through accepting it, anyway.

You can even turn it into a *community wiki* answer right away (or later, see the small checkbox in the right corner below the answer box) and from then on won't gain any reputation. Also, by turning it into a *community wiki* answer, it's more obvious that you didn't come up with the answer yourself.

Also, properly attribute the source - something you did, so this looks fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did exactly this (including checking the community wiki marker).

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is all about *content*; it's less important who wrote something. ["Vote for content, not for the user"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232) is most often quoted in the context of serial voting, but it also applies to accept *votes* (yes, accepting an answer is a vote).

So go ahead and accept your answer if it helped you solve your problem, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that. You won't get any reputation from accepting your own answer, though.