# Blind experiment to evaluate upvote and downvote tendency by author reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I have a sneaking suspicion that the decision whether to upvote / downvote content relies heavily on the reputation of the author of the question.

This phenomenon is known as [the fallacy of origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_fallacy).

I am looking for volunteers with high reputation to help me conduct this experiment.

The experiment design would be a classic A/B testing, in which we would ask **the same** question from 2 different users.

**User A:** Would have a low reputation <100

**User B:** Would have a high reputation >5k

We would measure the amount of upvotes and downvotes per view, and apply a statistical significance test to evaluate the impact of the effect.

### Edit 11/11/2018: Ramhound Raised an interesting point in the comments.

Users who see the 2 versions of the question might behave differently.

Can we access the logs and query which user seen which question and when ?

Comment: The policy is to vote about question's content quality, not the OP's reputation. The outcome will be that many low rep users aren't able to provide quality answers or questions most of the time.

Comment: Policy is one thing, and user behaviour is another thing. Would you like to help me test this hypothesis ?

Comment: I believe such has been already tested earlier already.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367719/experiment-request-temporarily-stop-showing-characteristics-about-a-user-in-the

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close, because I don't believe this is relevant to the SE network at large; it's a survey request, which traditionally isn't a good fit on *any* SE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , If you happen to find that this experiment had been done before, I'd love to have a look at the results.

Comment: Since the ending question is a call for volunteers, I'm voting to close. (cc @fbueckert)

Comment: Considering the impetus for this question...I think a greater understanding of what SE is, and what our goal is, is needed.  We are not a forum, nor help desk.  Those expectations are what lead to these types of requests, and learning more about the network brings the perspective more in line with what we're trying to build here.

Comment: Perhaps the reason why my request for an experiment over on MSO was positively received is that I kept open the possibility of it not being the case, and I provided a clear argument. @UriGoren I think you should have a look at it to see what kind of requests get positively received here.

Comment: Well, this just got weirder.  How, exactly, is this supposed to be controlled?  Not much of an experiment if there's no process, no control, and no oversight.  So I don't think anything constructive is going to come of this.

Comment: @fbueckert, this is a controlled experiment in which the only feature we are testing is the author's reputation. Classic A/B testing scheme, what do you find lacking in this experiment design ?

Comment: Like I said: No process; there's no way to account for outliers at all.  No control; you haven't organized this in any sense.  It's an experiment born of sour grapes, not methodical thought.  And finally, no oversight; you can skew the results however you want, because there won't be any.  As controlled experiments go...this one isn't.

Comment: @fbueckert, It's pretty amusing that you said "It's an experiment born of sour grapes", because this argument relies on the fallacy of origins itself. But nevertheless, how do you suggest to conduct an experiment to evaluate the effect of reputation on up/down voting tendency ?

Comment: Well, considering we have users that quite often create new accounts, to test various aspects, and have no issues gaining upvotes for them, I believe the experiment is unnecessary.  Experience with the system shines through.  The hypothesis is entirely flawed.

Comment: Here's my suggestion for [User B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375554/why-are-high-rep-users-discouraged-from-asking-questions) Note he or she has 150K rep and seems not to think that they are in receipt of any kind of free pass.

Comment: I suggest you read my version that I've linked above for a good example of a controlled experiment with a process.

Comment: @UriGoren - The problem with your test is that most users in a community, will recognize the fact the same question, has been asked more than once.  **If I saw the same exact question twice, I would simply assume, they were the same person.**

Comment: @Ramhound, that's a valid point. optimally we should expose users to only one version of the question. But if that's not an option, we should measure the amount of users who were exposed to 2 versions (cross contaminations). I have no idea if we have access to this data, do we know which user seen which question ?

Comment: @Ramhound, I've edited your comment into the original question, that's a super important insight. Do you happen to know if we have access to this data ?

Comment: @UriGoren - Does the community have access, no, it does not.

Answer (score 9):

> I have a sneaking suspicion that the decision whether to upvote / downvote content relies heavily on the reputation of the author of the question.

Nobody doubts that the fallacy of origins holds on Stack Exchange to a certain degree, even though we are instructed to [vote for the content, not the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232). If you've just been on the receiving end of a few downvotes as a new users, the effect feels much stronger than it actually is. However, Stack Exchange is not a place for conducting experiments, not even about the site itself.

> We would measure the amount of upvotes and downvotes per view, and apply a statistical significance test to evaluate the impact of the effect.

With N = 1 question, I'm quite sure that the statistical significance will be almost zero. Also, one of the questions would almost surely be closed as a duplicate of the other, influencing the votes as well.

Comment: "Nobody doubts that the fallacy of origins holds on Stack Exchange" What evidence I've seen (which is a decent amount) has shown that the effect is, at best, very small.  Certainly way smaller than people like the OP are claiming it is.  As such, I'd say *I* would say it doesn't hold (to a meaningful degree).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, obviously we will need to post several questions (that could be deleted later) in order to gain a significant result.

Comment: @Servy certainly, the effect looks to be bigger if you're a relative newcomer, and on the receiving end of a few downvotes. I know that my own thought process works partially like 'hey, I know that user, (s)he knows what (s)he is talking about.' (I can often resist the urge to immediately upvote, though.)

Comment: @Glorfindel In such cases the *entirety* of the difference (to a close approximation anyway) in those situations is that newer people don't know how they are expected to act, and those that have experience on the site do, and so their actual actions are different.  Whenever you see experienced users using new accounts you see behaviors similar to when using their older accounts, demonstrating that this effect is, at best, very small.  That some people *think* it's a notable effect doesn't mean it *is* a notable effect.

Comment: @Servy, have you looked at the distribution of reputation ? users with less than 200 rep are more than 90% of the users. Obviously this kind of bias could have a disastrous effect on newcomers ability to gain reputation.

Comment: @UriGoren Sure, most users haven't posted *at all*.  They've literally created an account and done *actual* nothing (public) with it.  What's your point?  What is disastrous about having lots of low privileged (mostly inactive) users?

Comment: If this bias holds, then a newcomer is stuck in a vicious cycle of "low rep"->"low upvote rate"->"low rep"->...  I think that the rational action to do, is to test this hypothesis rather than assume it doesn't hold...

Comment: @UriGoren you can check sites like The Workplace or Interpersonal Skills, where veteran users often post under a new, 'anonymous' account if they're posting 'sensitive' questions they'd rather not associate with their real account. But the quality of questions is the same.

Comment: However, those kind of questions are often HNQ material (though not anymore in the case of IPS.SE) so the voting on them is kinda skewed anyway.

Comment: @UriGoren So how do you think people that have reputation earned it if it's impossible for low rep users to earn any reputation?  How do you explain all of the people that have started new accounts *recently* and had no problem earning reputation?  Given that all of the evidence suggests that new users posting good content have no problem earning reputation, what's the basis for your assertion that new users can't earn reputation?  And, as mentioned, almost all of those low privileged accounts are entirely inactive.  They're not "not getting upvotes", they're just *not posting*.

Comment: @Servy, you are basically mentioning a "Survival Bias", nothing is impossible, just less probable. I would love to elaborate more on experiment design and statistics, but this falls beyond the scope of this comment. I am sure you can find a way to contact me (or do the the research yourself) if you're truly interested.

Comment: @UriGoren Yes, there is a survival bias.  Users that post quality content get upvotes and continue posting, people that post low quality content get downvotes and don't keep posting (well, hopefully, sadly in practice they often don't stop).  That said, most of the low privileged accounts aren't users that "quit" because they got bad feedback, they're users that  *never posted in the first place* or people that created an account to ask one question and then didn't bother keeping the account (simply making a new one if they have another question at some point in the future).

Comment: @UriGoren But what the evidence *doesn't* show is that people posting useful content don't get upvotes just because of their existing reputation.

Comment: @Servy, sorry, I don't understand your definitions. what is "useful content", what is "don't get upvotes" ?
has anyone measured the `upvote-rate` and `downvote-rate` as a function of user reputation ?
This is exactly what my original experiment is designed to test

Comment: @UriGoren Given that you don't understand such fundamental concepts of the site I think it's pretty safe to say that you haven't done enough research to be at the point of trying to do large scale experiments.  You should take the time to learn what the community considers useful content, look at the *existing* data already available to you on upvote and downvote rates.  You appear to be lacking an understanding of too many fundamentals to either successfully implement a large scale experiment, or to meaningfully interpret the results, given that lack of understanding of core concepts.

Comment: @UriGoren You have been told before that you're expected to be doing some research before asking questions, and that was given to you as a major problem with your earlier contributions.  You've claimed that being told the problem would help you fix it, and yet you've *continued* to demonstrate a lack of research before posting, and an unwillingness to do it.  That's not a good sign.

Comment: "However, Stack Exchange is not a place for conducting experiments, not even about the site itself." Why not? This is a bad mentality to have.

Comment: @Servy, I don't find these Ad-Hominem attacks productive. Please take a look at my profile, and consider whether I have the skills to conduct a statistical experiment. You might also find this interesting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337143/is-there-a-downvote-rate-per-tag-statistic

Comment: @UriGoren As has been told to you earlier, providing evidence, in the form of your own actions, that contradicts the points that you're making, is not an ad hominem attack.  It's just providing evidence.  An ad hominem attack would be bringing up irrelevant personal information in an attempt to generate bias.  You having experience with statistics doesn't mean you're familiar enough about a particular topic to do an experiment on it.  I'm claiming you lack the domain knowledge, not the statistical knowledge. As for the link, what is that intended to show?  What did you learn from the question?

Comment: @Servy, Ad hominem is referring to properties of the **author** in order to disqualify the validity of an **argument**. You referring to your perception of my history or my past actions, is exactly an ad hominem attack. I would expect that someone who is so vested into SE like yourself would bother to google "ad hominem" if he is not sure he understands it. But hey, its easier to post something on SE rather than doing some research, right ?

Comment: @UriGoren - Using past behavior as an example, and to specifically explain how to avoid downvotes, is not an ad hominem attack.  Nobody is attacking you.  However, your past behavior cannot be ignored, given the fact your downvotes were issued to the quality of your questions not due to the amount of magical internet points you might not have.

Comment: @Ramhound, if you followed my questions on the meta sites, you can see I could not care less what my reputation on MSE is. My goal is to make SE sites (and stackoverflow in particularly) more welcoming for newcomers. I believe that step zero in our effort to make SE a more accepting community, is to measure the scale of the problem. The experiment design I posted in my question is meant to do exactly that. Without data, every decision we make is a guess.

Comment: @UriGoren - Does not appear the community would agree with that conclusion.

Comment: Less than a 100 people even viewed this post, I would not rush in to conclusions on what the community "agrees" or "disagrees".

Comment: @UriGoren Using Wikipedia's definition, "Ad hominem [...], is a fallacious argumentative strategy **whereby genuine discussion of the topic at hand is avoided** by instead attacking the character, motive, or other attribute of the person making the argument, or persons associated with the argument, **rather than attacking the substance of the argument itself**."  I did not do that.  I stated facts about your actions that specifically contradict the arguments that you were making, rather than stating facts about you that are irrelevant to the discussion at hand in an attempt to discredit you.