# How can I upvote/mark an edit on my post as helpful?

Tags: feature-request, edits

I had one of my answers polished up by another user.

It was good, and now it's even better, however when I reviewed my edit history I find no way to upvote the edit, or mark it as helpful.

People who do this type of thing are truly valuable to the community as they improve readability and make answers easier to understand for other users.

Comment: Approved suggested edits net the editor a whopping +2 reputation. Else there are some badges, but that's it.

Comment: What would you suggest we do?

Answer (score 4):

> People who do this type of thing are truly valuable to the community as they improve readability and make answers easier to understand for other users.

Yes, I completely agree with this. Note that if that was a user with less than 2000 reputation, they did this via a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/295232) and they already got 2 reputation for having the edit accepted (=marked helpful).

IMHO, the best way to pay it forward would be to significantly improve one of *their* posts. If they don't have one (that you can improve), pick another post on the site which needs some polishing. Or just contribute to the community as a whole by writing another good post.

Editors can be ['pinged' in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232) so you could use that for thanking them; however, that's not what [comments are meant for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and you should definitely remove the comment after they've read it.

<s>I am</s> [my bot](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) is making quite a lot of edits across the network nowadays. What I experience is that sometimes after such an edit, I get a random upvote (or, less often, a downvote) on one of my posts on the affected site. That is *not* how it should work: you should [vote for the content, not for the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232).