# Rules which Meta Stack Exchange moderators need to follow regarding adding [status-review] tag in conflict of interest cases

Tags: support, tags, meta, moderators, moderator-tags

[Meta Stack Exchange moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to a post when Stack Exchange staff can give an appropriate response to the post.

I am curious to know about the rules which Meta Stack Exchange moderators need to follow before adding the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag for few kinds of questions.

- Let's say a user who wasn't a moderator in Meta Stack Exchange posted couple of feature requests, bugs, etc. in Meta Stack Exchange in the past. Now the user is a moderator. Can they add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their old posts?
- Let's talk about a user who is currently a Meta Stack Exchange moderator. Can the moderator add the the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their question in the first revision itself?
- Can a Meta Stack Exchange moderator add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag in the posts of their fellow moderators? Or are only CMs allowed to add [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag in questions of moderators?

---

I do know that moderators have super-powers and they *[can (to be able to)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can)* do all the aforementioned stuff. But, I would like to know if they *can (are to be allowed to)* do it and what the standard practices are.

---

I do not feel that my post is a duplicate of [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642). That post does not talk much about adding the tag to one's own posts and other situations mentioned in my question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That post doesn't talk about adding status-review to one's own posts.

Comment: It doesn't have to. If that were a necessary consideration it would have been included in the thorough guidance found there.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov hmmm. Let's see what the mods might say.

Comment: Moving to leave open. That the other post doesn't talk about this case is more likely because it wasn't considered rather than considered and decided not to enact rules for/against.

Comment: Leaving open too, it is in no way a duplicate of the proposed target. Answers must be *directly* applicable for a dupe closure to be valid. Also of note: "absence of documentation" !== "not a necessary consideration".

Comment: BTW: Regarding your use of "can": If you're going to use a secondary definition, then it's better to just use a word or words which primarily mean what you intend, rather than having to explain that you're specifically using a non-primary definition. For example, you could use "may", "permitted to", "should", etc.

Comment: My bad... I'll order new glasses tomorrow

Answer (score 14):

One of the golden rules of moderation (both for ♦ moderators and regular users performing moderation tasks): don't act when there might be a conflict of interest. Yes, you can act on your own posts, but only if it's rather obvious that your action is right. (Some examples: rolling back a bad edit on your post, or flagging an abusive comment.)

So,

> Can they add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their old posts?

I haven't done so yet, but I might do it if it aligns with the current priorities of staff (as outlined in the [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375561/295232)) and if it has enough support. I *try* (but might fail) not to distinguish between my old posts and others' old posts, though obviously I know my posts better.

> Can the moderator add the the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their question in the first revision itself?

Perhaps, if it's a rather critical bug caused by a recent deploy. On the other hand, staff is likely to monitor Meta Stack Exchange at such moments, and in my experience pings in the Teachers' Lounge work at least as well, so the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag is often superfluous.

> Can a Meta Stack Exchange moderator add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag in the posts of their fellow moderators?

When looking at a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) candidate, I try not to take into account who posted it. Stack Exchange is about [the content, not the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232), and this is no exception.

Comment: An additional example: When I was an RPG.SE mod (i.e. before I was a CM), I did add the [status-review] tag to one of my feature requests on our site's meta – but I only did so after discussing it with the other mods of the site.

Comment: @Glorfindel I tried my best... I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, with our *own* posts we tend to try to avoid conflicts of interest. I would much rather have another moderator make the decision, ideally without too much prompting. There are no formal rules, but as folks who've been handed the keys and trusted to make the right decisions, we kind of try to live up to that trust, and do our best for the community.

Looking at my status-* posts (since [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) isn't an accurate indicator) - a good number *were* retagged by CMs - but it's less "Mods can't", and more "this fits our current roadmap" or "this might be worth looking at in future".

Ideally, a *significant* number of review retags are from the [current roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca).

As a moderator — especially on MSE, I have a special relationship/level of visibility with both my fellow MSE mods and many of the folks working for the company. *Personally* (perhaps a little hubristically), I feel my ideas should speak for themselves and there is no need for me to retag my own posts for attention.

Having said all that:

TLDR: We *can*, but we *generally avoid it*.

> Let's say a user who wasn't a moderator in Meta Stack Exchange posted couple of feature requests, bugs, etc. in Meta Stack Exchange in the past. Now the user is a moderator. Can they add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their old posts?

If it fits the roadmap and has merit, theoretically yes. In practice, I'd personally rather get another mod, or a CM, to review.

> Let's talk about a user who is currently a Meta Stack Exchange moderator. Can the moderator add the the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to their question in the first revision itself?

In theory, yes. However, for a question that's currently on the roadmap or urgent, generally, discussion of the issue should be sufficient to figure out if a tag is warranted — and whichever diamond holder is convinced can do so. If it's *clear* that it needs attention/be in the ticketing system, it doesn't really matter who tags it. If there's, say, a potentially network-breaking issue, and the other mods are not available, I'd just go for it.

> Can a Meta Stack Exchange moderator add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag in the posts of their fellow moderators? Or are only CMs allowed to add [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag in questions of moderators?

If it has merit, certainly. There's no formal or informal rule that we can't retag a fellow mod's post; if it needs attention, and fits other criteria, who posted it shouldn't matter.