# Can I upvote multiple posts from the same person if they are helpful?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer, up-votes, serial-voting

I posted a few questions on Stack Overflow. After getting answers, I felt like they were all right as they solved my problems. So, I accepted all of them.

From then, whenever I visit the website, I check their answers to other questions. I started upvoting their answers where I feel like they are helpful.

Is it okay to upvote answers from the same people regularly if they are accepted and helpful for others? Are there any policies against this kind of activity?

I am new to this site. If what I'm doing is wrong or against the policy means I won't upvote from now.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/616624) - but worth reading, anyway. Officially, your votes should be based on *content* rather than on *authorship*. While there may be some overlap in these, actively seeking out posts from a specific user may well be construed as inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I posted a few questions on Stack Overflow. After getting the answers, I felt like they are all right as they solved my problems. So, I accepted all of them.

Great, thanks!

> From then, whenever I'm visiting that website, I keep on checking their answers to other questions too. So, I started upvoting the answers where I feel like they are helpful.

That's not what you should do though. This is [serial upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232) and will be reversed by the system. Stack Exchange is [all about the content, not the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232). It's also hard to distinguish your situation (many upvotes to a random user) and somebody who mass upvotes a friend/colleague/somebody who paid them to do it.

I forgot where I saw it, but a good rule of thumb is that you should **never vote on a post which you visited from a user's profile**. If you're mostly active in a niche tag or on a community with low traffic and few answerers, you might also end up upvoting the same user repeatedly, but the risk that that happens is much lower.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know all these. I won't repeat it again. For now, my account is safe right ?? And again can't I accept multiple answers for my question if both are helpful?

Comment: Yes, no problems. You can't accept multiple answers but you could award [bounties](/help/bounty).

Comment: "*I forgot where I saw it, but a good rule of thumb is that you should* **never vote on a post which you visited from a user's profile**." Says who? Do you know how many posts by my favourite author I have upvoted because I **read** each and **every one of them** and then upvoted. I made sure not to do it on one day but what's wrong spread over weeks and months? Barrie England and ShreevatsaR are but two of my favourite users on EL&U, alas no longer active.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні says the serial upvoting link in this answer and my answer (which happens to be the same link).

Comment: I know what serial upvoting is, I have been targeted myself and I used to flag the upvotes because it was easy to tell that the users would spend mere seconds before upvoting my contributions. I want to make it clear that if someone is a fan of a user, there's nothing wrong with that. In fact, I learnt a lot by reading  posts by my favourite users, there used to be many, and admiring how they wrote. Obviously, what I am talking about is different to programming where solutions to problems are prized over quality and consistency.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні just out of curiosity, what makes you think that in programming we value quality and consistency less than solutions regardless of the former?

Comment: Because the main focus on programming sites is on the solution. Does it work? Yes. It's then accepted. If the answer then goes on to explain in detail then it probably attracts greater consensus from the community. But I should also include **experience** and **expertise** . New programmers and developers are unlikely to know as much.

Comment: @Akshay98 it's impossible to give more than one green check mark, known as **accepting**, for every question you post but you can certainly **upvote** more than one contribution if they have *helped* you.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні it's a rule of thumb, not a law. You're experienced enough to know when you can/should do what you describe, most users aren't.

Comment: "It's a rule of thumb" I can happily agree with but not with  "never", and  while some  inexperienced and younger users may succumb to the tentation of upvoting a series of posts by their heroes, I don't think it's such a widespread phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

You should not target individuals by looking at all their posts from their profile and voting on them. That's called [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and is against the rules. It's usually automatically reversed, but if you continue it will likely get you in trouble.

Look for questions and answers you find helpful, not people.

Accepting answers on questions you've asked that you found helpful, is a good thing. Do feel free to carry on doing that.