# Can you comment or vote on a revision?

Tags: support, edits

How do you comment on a revision? [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4840817/revisions)

It would also be nice to have a vote button to appreciate a revision change.

Comment: Why? What is there useful to say? "Great bold font!! +1."

Comment: You can already get permanent links to specific revisions, and mention these in the comment section of a question or answer post. Why do you need something more?

Comment: Why stick a like buttom on the site. We're not a social network for handing out likes. It's enough to have a revert button to handling low-quality edits.

Comment: Note about closing: while it doesn't appear as full duplicate at first glance, OP made it clear they mean they want to award the good revisions by voting, and that's exactly the idea behind the duplicate.

Comment: Low-rep users already get +2 rep for a successfully suggested edit. Therefore, you can (inherently) "reward" them by *not* rolling back their edit..! Simples.

Answer (score 7):

You can leave a comment under the post; editors [can be pinged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232), and this is the way to address concerns of or improvements to the edit. (Apart from making another edit, of course.)

What matters most is the current / final state of a post; if that's good content, vote it up, even though the author of the post will get the reputation, not the editor. [Stack Exchange is about the content, not the users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232) Comments just thanking the editor (or author) are [noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and should not be posted.

Comment: ok but at least voting up a revision should be allowed the same way voting a comment is. It is a way to appreciate the effort somebody did and also to compute those points into their profile/reputation/etc. Stack Exchange is also about users otherwise users wouldn't have reputation/score in the first place.

Comment: @Gabe did you mean that voting up a revision will increase the reputation of the editor, not the poster? Comment upvotes don't give reputations, by the way.